# How to sum similar value in array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have array, like this and I want to join him by name:
Please help to decide problem.

```
$params[] = 
  [
    "name" => "Robert"
    "visitCount" => 2
    "coef" => "5.50"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Anna"
    "visitCount" => 1
    "coef" => "3.58"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Joe"
    "visitCount" => 1
    "coef" => "8.00"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Robert"
    "visitCount" => 2
    "coef" => "1.50"
  ]
```

How I can get concatenation similar name and sum of coef?

Result that I need:

```
[
    "name" => "Robert"
    "visitCount" => 2
    "coef" => "7.00"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Anna"
    "visitCount" => 1
    "coef" => "3.58"
  ],
  [
    "name" => "Joe"
    "visitCount" => 1
    "coef" => "8.00"
  ],
```

Comment: First of all, what have you tried? It's a fairly simple task. Create a grouping array `$sums` or whatever. Loop over your data and use the name as the array key; check if key exists; if yes, add coef to coef in `$sums` where name/key matches; if not, add all values to `$sums` with name as key.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$output = [];
foreach ($params as $obj) {
    $output[$obj['name']] = [
        'name' => $obj['name'],
        'visitCount' => $obj['visitCount'],
        'coef' => (isset($output[$obj['name']])) ? $obj['coef'] + $output[$obj['name']]['coef'] : $obj['coef']
    ];
}

// If you not want an assossiative array
$output = array_values($output);
```

Comment: Thank you for spelling out the code that solves this. If you added an explanation on how your code works and how it solves OP's problem, it would add to the value of your answer.